# How to change CSS for a specific page in wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress

I wanna change my CSS for a specific page, and I can not get the ID of that page.
I wonder how I can change my CSS for a specific page when I don't have a ID of that page?
This is the ID of my page: forum=forum-framtidsjouren

If I change the code below I'm changing other pages too...

```
.home #content, .single #content, .page #content 
{
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
box-shadow: none;
width: 100% !important; // I want to change width to 100% !important
}
```

Comment: Open up the inspector in your browser and navigate to the body tag and you will see something like this: `<body class="... postid-123 / page-id-123 ...">`

Comment: @biziclop, consider moving this to an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open up the inspector in your browser and navigate to the `<body>` tag and you will see something like this:

```
<body class="... postid-123 ...">
  or
<body class="... page-id-123 ...">
```

See the documentation of the `body_class()` function in WordPress, which is responsible for generating these classes:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class

Answer (score -2):

You could also use a plugin which allows you to load specific css files for some specific pages.

This one for instance: https://wordpress.org/plugins/this-page-needs-files/

Comment: I'd consider that solution pretty heavy-weight and needlessly prone to side effects for the given question.